# Where does PostGIS store data loaded shp2pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

When I install PostGIS, and its `address_standardizer` and `postgis_tiger_geocoder` extensions there are many tables created which I can see with `\dt`. What do these tables do and where does `shp2pgsql` load the shapefile?

To show this, an empty db, first what have the db? nothing, checking with `\dt`.

```
testgis=# -- Enable PostGIS (as of 3.0 contains just geometry/geography)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- enable raster support (for 3+)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
-- Enable PostGIS Advanced 3D
-- and other geoprocessing algorithms
-- sfcgal not available with all distributions
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- rule based standardizer
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer;
-- example rule data set
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  can not open the control file of extension «/usr/share/postgresql-13/extension/postgis_sfcgal.control»: File does not exist
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Now check with `\dt`.

With postgres user:

```
                  List of relations
 Schema |           Name           | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------------------------+-------+----------
 public | spatial_ref_sys          | table | postgres
 public | us_gaz                   | table | postgres
 public | us_lex                   | table | postgres
 public | us_rules                 | table | postgres
 tiger  | addr                     | table | postgres
 tiger  | addrfeat                 | table | postgres
 tiger  | bg                       | table | postgres
 tiger  | county                   | table | postgres
 tiger  | county_lookup            | table | postgres
 tiger  | countysub_lookup         | table | postgres
 tiger  | cousub                   | table | postgres
 tiger  | direction_lookup         | table | postgres
 tiger  | edges                    | table | postgres
 tiger  | faces                    | table | postgres
 tiger  | featnames                | table | postgres
 tiger  | geocode_settings         | table | postgres
 tiger  | geocode_settings_default | table | postgres
 tiger  | loader_lookuptables      | table | postgres
 tiger  | loader_platform          | table | postgres
 tiger  | loader_variables         | table | postgres
 tiger  | pagc_gaz                 | table | postgres
 tiger  | pagc_lex                 | table | postgres
 tiger  | pagc_rules               | table | postgres
 tiger  | place                    | table | postgres
 tiger  | place_lookup             | table | postgres
 tiger  | secondary_unit_lookup    | table | postgres
 tiger  | state                    | table | postgres
 tiger  | state_lookup             | table | postgres
 tiger  | street_type_lookup       | table | postgres
 tiger  | tabblock                 | table | postgres
 tiger  | tract                    | table | postgres
 tiger  | zcta5                    | table | postgres
 tiger  | zip_lookup               | table | postgres
 tiger  | zip_lookup_all           | table | postgres
 tiger  | zip_lookup_base          | table | postgres
 tiger  | zip_state                | table | postgres
 tiger  | zip_state_loc            | table | postgres
(37 rows)
```

With normal user:

```
            Listado de relaciones
 Esquema |     Nombre      | Tipo  |  Dueño   
---------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public  | spatial_ref_sys | tabla | postgres
 public  | us_gaz          | tabla | postgres
 public  | us_lex          | tabla | postgres
 public  | us_rules        | tabla | postgres
(4 filas)
```

Comment: You mean postgis creates new tables in your system? The only one visible to you should be the `spatial_ref_sys` table, and it is pretty much vital to postgis. Other than that, the data you import from a shp will be stored a single table.

Comment: there is, for a normal user, 4 tables, and from the superuser, a lot of tables...., well, maybe even with all this tables, all is stored in a single table.

Comment: Do you really need all those extensions? from your question one cannot assume you need `postgis_raster` or `postgis_topology`. I thought you were only using `postgis`

Comment: Note that all these extra tables are related to the extension `postgis_tiger_geocoder`. Do you really need this extension?

Comment: Here is projects with geocoding, nodes, rasters, and more things, so, how I'm starting with this, will take time to implement them, but due to the nature how I want/need to use them, I need to know how postgis organize the data, to can modify it in the future, this can be clarified case by case, is very helpful the comments, like, ```spatial_ref_sys``` belongs only to tables with geometries and all the data is stored in a single table.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate if you specify, that is only for postgis alone, to in case, other ppl who know the answer post or comment about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shp2pgsql` will by default create one table for each imported shapefile. However, you can have it load multiple shapefiles into the same table using the `-a` option.

The table `spatial_ref_sys`, as the name suggests, only keeps the data for the spatial reference systems, which are vital for operations like coordinates transformation.

The tables `us_gaz`, `us_lex`, and `us_rules` are related to the extension [`address_standardizer`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/tree/f6def67654c25d812446239036cee44812613748/extensions/address_standardizer).

The other tables in the schema `tiger` are related to the extension [`postgis_tiger_geocoder`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/tree/f6def67654c25d812446239036cee44812613748/extras/tiger_geocoder) - also system tables that shouldn't really worry about.